# Can't appendChild to article

Tags: javascript, html, rest, web

I'm trying to fetch content from my Restful api and append it to a html file but somehow new article tags are not created. The main tag exists and the responseContent is confirmed to actually contain the values. Any ideas why this code wont work?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        responseArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);      
        var anchorElement = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];       

        for(var index = 0; index < responseArray.length; index++){
             //tried replacing appendChild with += as well
             anchorElement.appendChild(createLayout(responseArray[index]));
        }       
    }
}


function createLayout(responseContent){
    console.log(responseContent);
    var article = document.createElement("article");    

    var header = document.createElement("header"), h4 = 
    document.createElement("h4");
    //header.textContent = responseContent.title;
    h4.textContent = "Title of event";
    header.appendChild(h4);

    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.textContent = responseContent.date + " " + responseContent.time;
    console.log("article: " + article);

    return article;
```

}

Comment: You never append to the article. All you return is `document.createElement('article')`

Comment: Can you post an example response? What does this.responseText contain?

Comment: Can you confirm the responseArray.length value?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to append your created h4 and p to the article

```
function createLayout(responseContent){
    console.log(responseContent);
    var article = document.createElement("article");    

    var header = document.createElement("header"), h4 = 
    document.createElement("h4");
    //header.textContent = responseContent.title;
    h4.textContent = "Title of event";
    header.appendChild(h4);

    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.textContent = responseContent.date + " " + responseContent.time;
    console.log("article: " + article);
    // missing
    article.appendChild(h4);
    article.appendChild(paragraph);
    // __________
    return article;
}
```

The way you have it now, your function only returns the created `article` element - basicaly like

```
function createLayout(responseContent) {
    return document.createElement("article"); 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything sadly, when I view the source in Chrome nothing is added

Comment: @Rem you won't see the added elements when you view the source since they are dynamically added on runtime. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I get it well, I assume that you wish to have the article tag included in your html.

You are missing to call: `document.body.appendChild(article);` once you are ready to include the article in your page.

If you want to give `header` to the `article` you should call `article.appendChild(header);`

it would give something like this at the end

```
    var article = document.createElement("article");    

var header = document.createElement("header"), h4 = 
    document.createElement("h4");
//header.textContent = responseContent.title;
h4.textContent = "Title of event";
header.appendChild(h4);

console.log(header);
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
paragraph.textContent = responseContent.date + " " + responseContent.time;
article.appendChild(header); //if you would like to append header to article
console.log(article);

document.body.appendChild(article); //if you would like to append article to <body></body>
```

Hope this will help, and let me know if I am misunderstanding something

Comment: >document.body.appendChild(article);   Made it work but I still can't append to <main> no matter which suggestion I try

Comment: you might try to get your element with the tag `<main>` and append the article to it like so  `document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].appendChild(article)`

Comment: and remove `document.body.appendChild(article);` because it would override the whole html